# Java Image Panel File Import

Tags: java, image, panel

I am currently having an issue with my code that it won't import an image from the file dialog. Basically it's meant to import the image when selected and place it on an Image Panel which is implemented.
Here is the code I have written for the File Import

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog((Frame)null, "Select File to Open");
dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
dialog.setVisible(true);
String file = dialog.getFile();
imageP.readImage(file);
imageP.repaint();
```

Here is the Image Panel Class

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{
    int numCols, numRows;
    BufferedImage image = null;
    private final int xOffset = 0;
    private final int yOffset = 0;

    public ImagePanel()
    {
        readImage("");
    }

    public void readImage(String filename)
    {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
            numRows = image.getHeight();
            numCols = image.getWidth();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        if (image != null)
        {
            g2.drawImage( image, xOffset, yOffset, null );
        }
    }
}
```

I currently get an IIOException which says can't read file at the moment.
If anyone can help me with this issue that would be great.

Comment: In `readImage`, call `repaint` after the image is loaded. Also, I don't know why `readImage` doesn't just accept a reference to `File`. I also don't know why you're not using `JFileChooser`.  I would check the return result of `FileDialog#getFile` and verify that the file you are trying to load is actually a image format supported by `ImageIO`

Comment: I had a file that I had used by setting the file name directly in the code instead of importing through File Dialog and the photo shows up. I hadn't been using JFileChooser because I was going off what out lecturer had used in our slides at first but if it works better I see no reason not to change.

Comment: I changed the code to use a JFileChooser and passed a file into readImage instead. Now it works. So thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Why use a panel for this, rather than a `JLabel`? The label can display an image without needing to be extended, unlike the panel. The label will also return a preferred size based on the image size.